# Element's background color in selenium/robotframework

Tags: selenium, robotframework

Is there a way to get the background color of an the element in selenium robotframework? I'm trying with get attribute but it won't work and returns `None`

here is the html

```
<li pl-repeat="(slideId, slideContents) in slides" pl-click="viewSlide(slideContents['w-l'].url, slideId)" pl-class="{checked : slideId == viewSlideKey}" class="pl-scope checked"><span class="pl-binding">Draft</span></li>
```

Comment: Could you share your HTML??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do it using javascript 
`return document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(document.getElementByID("ID"),null)['background-color']`

if it's a class then same thing but `document.getElementsByClassName("class-name")[0],null)['background-color']`

Answer (score 4):

Although you can use JavaScript to get the computed style, I believe the idiomatic way of getting the style would be to use Selenium's API. Once you obtain a [webelement](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#module-selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement) reference using [Get Webelement](http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/doc/Selenium2Library.html#Get%20Webelement), you can use the [value_of_css_property](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/_modules/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.html#WebElement.value_of_css_property) method to get the background color.

```
Open Browser    https://www.stackoverflow.com    gc
${elem}    Get Webelement    css=.post-tag
${bg color}    Call Method    ${elem}    value_of_css_property    background-color
```

> Result: ${bg color} = rgba(225, 236, 244, 1)

One difference I noted here in this test is that value_of_css_property returned the rgba value whereas getComputedStyle returned only rgb.

[Selenium2LibraryExtension](https://github.com/axon-id/Selenium2LibraryExtension) attempts to make this easier by implementing [Element Background Color Should Be](https://axon-id.github.io/Selenium2LibraryExtension/#Element%20Background%20Color%20Should%20Be). value_of_css_property is used there as well.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer (even for newer versions of Robot framework and SeleniumLibrary) since it's based on the actual Selenium API. The javascript from the accepted answer is more of a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Element's background color in selenium/robotframework

Assuming the "Month" button has an id="monthButton" and is highlighted in a certain colour:

```
Wait Until Element Is Visible    id=monthButton    timeout=10s
${class}    Get Element Attribute    id=monthButton    class
Should Contain    ${class}    highlighted
```